# Trouble with calling function using onPressed in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to call a function upon an onPressed in Flutter.

I've tried

```
onPressed: (){ 
   _showDialog;
},
```

and

```
onPressed: _showDialog,
```

and

```
onPressed: () => _showDialog,
```

This is my function.

```
  void _showDialog() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Title"),
          content: Text("Body"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text("Close"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

I keep getting "invalid constant value".

EDIT:

This is where I'm calling onPressed:

```
                      secondary: const IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.domain),
                        onPressed: (){
                          _showDialog();
                        },
                      ),
```

[image: Error when onPressed]

Comment: a goog and clear question

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Easy fix: remove **const** keyword

```
      secondary: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.domain),
                    onPressed: (){
                      _showDialog();
                    },
                  ),
```

**Old Answer**

You should try like these ways:

```
onPressed: (){ 
   _showDialog();
},
```

or

```
onPressed: _showDialog,
```

or

```
onPressed: () => _showDialog(),
```

Comment: I'm still getting the "Invalid constant value" error

Comment: could you add the error log ? also add the code when you call onPressed

Comment: Sorry my code does not run so there is no error log. _showDialog is underlined in red and when the mouse is placed over it the error is shown to be "Invalid constant value". I have updated my question with the code.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my question with the Screenshot.

Comment: Same problem here, any solution?

Comment: This is because on your upper tree, somewhere there is another "const" (or even more than one). Trace everything up to the root and remove any "const" keywords you find.

Answer (score 6):

You need to check and remove contanier(widget) `const`
like this

## (X)

```
child: TextFormField(
                decoration: **const** InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye),
                      onPressed: showPassword,
                  ),
                  labelText: "Name *",
                  hintText: "Your Github account username",
                ),
              )
```

## (O)

```
child: TextFormField(
                decoration:InputDecoration(
                 ...
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove **const** keyword

**Your Code**

```
   secondary: const IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.domain),
                onPressed: (){
                  _showDialog();
                },
              ),
```

**Updated one**

```
   secondary: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.domain),
                onPressed: (){
                  _showDialog();
                },
              ),
```

Comment: the answer is as it was in my own opinion and it is possible to have same answers. but, is it wrong to do that?

Comment: yes, in future people would come to find solution for their problems and it would make harder for them to read all the answers. if your solution was already mentioned, you could just upvote it.

Answer (score -2):

For some scenarios you can declare top-level or static function:

```
  static void myHandler() {
    _showDialog();
  }
```

...

```
  secondary: const IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.domain),
                onPressed: myHandler,
              ),
```

Only in this case (top-level or static) myHandler can be treated as a constant and passed to the constant constructor.